# On screen keyboard not working for custom input field

Tags: angular

I am trying to get an on screen keyboard to work with a custom input field however I get an error stating `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'substr'`. On a normal input field this keyboard works perfectly.

App component HTML

```
<cb-form adobeFrmcontainer="registration-setupform" [formGroup]="setupForm">
  <form-input
    appOskInput
    [formStatus]="formStatus"
    [parentFormGroup]="setupForm"
    [data]="{
                        formControlName: 'accountNumber',
                        name: 'accountNumber'
                        icon: '',
                        maxlength: '16' |translate
                      }">
  </form-input>
</cb-form>

<app-keyboard></app-keyboard>
```

Keyboard directive

```
private el: ElementRef

ngOnInit() {
    let thisStyle = window.getComputedStyle(this.el.nativeElement);
    this.measure = document.createElement("span");
    this.measure.style.position = "absolute";
    this.measure.style.right = "100%";
    this.measure.style.font = thisStyle.font;
    document.body.appendChild(this.measure);
}

private onKey(key: string) {
        let element = this.el.nativeElement,
          start = element.selectionStart,
          end = element.selectionEnd;
        console.log("key element: "+element);
        this.measure.textContent = element.value.substr(0, start) + key;
        element.value = element.value.substr(0, start) + key + element.value.substr(end);
        element.focus();
        element.selectionStart = element.selectionEnd = start + 1;
    
        this.updateScrollPosition();
 }
```

The difference I See is that a normal input field returns `[object HTMLInputElement]` in my `console.log("key element: "+element);` whereas the custom input field returns `[object HTMLElement]`

Any ideas please?

Comment: What is the content of element?

Comment: @rohithpoya I update to add more code. element is of type `ElementRef`

Comment: Can't you get the value from form? this.setupForm.get('accountNumber').value

Comment: @rohithpoya I'm not sure how I would pass that value from the component to the directive which is in a different file

Comment: As in the error, element.value in undefined, which means you are referencing a wrong element

Comment: You are passing [parentFormGroup]="setupForm" to directive. So the formGroup must be available in directive.

Comment: Can you paste the complete content in directive

Comment: @rohithpoya please see this stackblitz example

https://stackblitz.com/edit/onscreen-keyboard?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

The only difference is that I have a custom input field as a pose to a normal input field `<input />`


This example works fine as the input field returns `[object HTMLInputElement]` whereas on my input fierld it returns `[object HTMLElement]`

Comment: I have added the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Element you are referring is a html element instead of a input element.  It is the reference of custom element `<form-input>`. You need get the input element from the htmlelement reference.

```
let inputEl = element.querySelector('input');
this.measure.textContent = inputEl.value.substr(0, start) + key;
```