# Form values from custom HTML element input field not displaying when using on-screen keyboard

Tags: javascript, angular, on-screen-keyboard

I am trying to get values that I type using an on-screen keyboard into a custom HTML element input field to display.

However I am currently getting empty strings. If I use a normal input field then it works fine.

Here is a snippet of my code and a stackblitz example which will have detailed code.

HTML

```
<form-input
    appOskInput
    [formStatus]="formStatus"
    [parentFormGroup]="setupForm"
    [data]="{
             formControlName: 'email',
             name: 'email'
            }">
</form-input>

<app-keyboard></app-keyboard>
```

Keyboard directive

```
 private onKey(key: string) {
    let element = this.el.nativeElement;
    let inputEl = element.querySelector('input');
    let start = inputEl.selectionStart;
    let end = inputEl.selectionEnd;
    this.measure.textContent = inputEl.value.substr(0, start) + key;
    inputEl.value = inputEl.value.substr(0, start) + key + inputEl.value.substr(end);
    if (this.control)
    this.control.control.setValue(inputEl.value)
    inputEl.focus();
    inputEl.selectionStart = inputEl.selectionEnd = start + 1;
    this.updateScrollPosition();
 }
```

Here is the stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/onscreen-keyboard-hlmkvv?file=src/app/app.component.ts

You will see that the values are displaying when inputted from a normal input field but I can't get the same to happen when using my custom HTML element input field. I have commented out the custom HTML input field in the code on the HTML page. Can anyone help please?

Comment: If it works on a normal input, should work on any. You did not provide the code with the form-input module. Are you sure you are importing the apposkinput directive into that module? That module likely has the error. https://stackoverflow.com/a/41505626/1779362

Comment: @user1779362 The custom input is an HTML element and not a normal input element. Please see this question I had previously asked where I was assisted to determine an HTML element vs Input element
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71598200/on-screen-keyboard-not-working-for-custom-input-field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Issue:**

You are adding the directive to a custom element & listening the events on the **custom element instead of actual input field**. Since, you have `@HostListener` for `focus` & `blur` events inside the directive, these events don't fire in case of custom component. Because your custom component doesn't fire `focus` and `blur` events. (If we want any custom element to be focusable, we add `tabindex=0` to make it focusable in the natural tabbing order of the webpage).

**Why it work on native input elements?**

Because native input elements emit `focus` & `blur` events. Therefore, you are able to see the virtual keyboard when you apply the directive to native `input`.

**Solution:**

You need to add event listeners to the native `input` field inside your custom component. Since, the directive is generic, you can use `querySelector()` on the nativeElement inside `OskInputDirective` to access the particular input field.

In `OskInputDirective`, add `focus` & `blur` listeners in `ngAfterViewInit`:

```
 ngAfterViewInit(){
    this.inputEl=this.el.nativeElement.querySelector('input');
    this.inputEl?.addEventListener('focus',this.onFocus.bind(this));
    this.inputEl?.addEventListener('blur',this.onBlur.bind(this));
  }
```

Now, you can use `this.inputEl` to refer to the input element inside your `onKey()` method.

**Note 1:** Here, we are binding the callbacks with the context of `OskInputDirective`. Else, `this` will refer to the DOM event.

**Note 2:** Since we are manually subscribing to the DOM event, Angular won't be able to detect changes & update your `FormControl` value. You need to emit an event when you change the `input` value from virtual keyboard.

In `onKey()`, call event emitter at the end. Now, listen to this event in the parent & update the corresponding form control value:

```
this.inputChanged.emit(element.value);
    this.updateScrollPosition();
```

Here is the forked stackblitz with a custom input element created for reference. https://stackblitz.com/edit/onscreen-keyboard-na5kqr?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: I still see an empty value alerted on the name field when I click the submit button

Comment: @skydev Updated my answer & the stackblitz